# Find the secret word in this encrypted image (part 2)

Tags: cipher, lateral-thinking

While walking around aimlessly and bored, you find a piece of paper on the sidewalk containing a heck of a lot of numbers. Normally someone seeing that would be like "ain't nobody got time for that" but you are just barely curious enough to wonder if there could be a secret meaning in there somewhere. Your instinct says that it actually won't take very long at all, and that when you figure it out, they will give you a secret word.

What is the secret word the numbers refer to?

(The numbers have been transcribed [here](http://pastebin.com/cF9cDv1v) for your convenience)

[image: Solve me if you dare.]

Full resolution image (not necessary don't waste time on it): https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rXdk.png

Comment: ain't nobody got time for that

Comment: @randal'thor my last puzzle got solved too quickly so I made this one slightly tougher. There are enough clues to solve though so I don't think I'll need to give hints.

Comment: I was just quoting you! :-))

Comment: @randal'thor ah okay I'm always paranoid that my puzzles may drift towards busywork territory if I'm not careful.

Comment: I moved the numbers to a Pastebin; if you want to keep them in the post for some reason, just roll it back.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, I copy-pasted the numbers into *Mathematica*:

```
str = "181 ... 29";
```

Next I convert the string to a list of numbers:

```
numbers = FromDigits /@ StringSplit[str];
```

Now, is this a decimal ASCII string?

```
FromCharacterCode[Take[numbers, 10]]
(* "µæ\.1dµæ\.1dµæ\.1dµ" *)
```

Evidently not.  Next I look at the letter frequencies:

```
Histogram[numbers, {1}]
```

[image]

It looks like there are just a few peaks.  Are all three main peaks the same height?

```
Commonest[numbers]
(* {181, 230, 29} *)
```

Yes, they are.  In fact, looking at the numbers, it starts off with this triple repeated several times (why did I not notice that faster?).  Breaking into threes, we get a list 1600 elements long:

```
Length[numbers] / 3
(* 1600 *)
```

A large square of triples?  This smells like an image...

```
Image[Partition[Partition[numbers, 3], Sqrt[1600]], "Byte", Magnification -> 8]
```

[image]

So the word is, "stars."

Altogether this took around a minute thirty, a testament to the power of *Mathematica*.

Comment: I'm definitely going to make it past one hour for part 3 >.<

Comment: Wait until I tell you how long it took me to solve it...

Comment: Nice job, this makes me want to learn Mathematica. Just two lines of code needed to solve this.

Answer (score 6):

I am not fast enough with programming/computer stuff to beat 2012rcampion, but here's my image screenshotted from Excel, and an explanation:

> [image]

Explanation: The numbers come in groups of three, and there are 1600 groups of three numbers. Throw them into a 40x40 grid, and translate each group of three into the RGB color scheme. That gives you a specific color for each "square" of the matrix, and gives you the message shown above: The word is stars!

Comment: Very interesting way of solving it since it's done in a way that most people would be familiar with. Did you do the cell coloring by hand or is there some excel trick for this?

Comment: There probably is an Excel trick for it, but all I did was a Find All for each sequence of numbers and then selected all of them and did a fill based on the RGB codes.

Comment: FYI for future generations: VBA could have cycled through the cells and colored them for you. `For Each cell In Cells: arr = Split(cell.Value): cell.Interior.Color = RGB(arr(0), arr(1), arr(2)): Next`

Answer (score 4):

Read about [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) then copy and paste the code below into the console, press enter, then scroll to the bottom of the page to see the resulting image.

```
var data=[].filter.call(document.getElementsByTagName('pre'),
            function(e){ return e.textContent && e.textContent.indexOf('181 230')==0 })
        [0].textContent.split(' ').map(
            function(e){ return parseInt(e,10)} );

var c=document.createElement('canvas');
document.body.appendChild(c);
c.width=40;
c.height=40;
var p=c.getContext('2d').getImageData(0,0,40,40);
for(var i=0; i<1600; i++){
        p.data[4*i]=data[3*i];
        p.data[4*i+1]=data[3*i+1];
        p.data[4*i+2]=data[3*i+2];
        p.data[4*i+3]=255;
};
c.getContext('2d').putImageData(p,0,0);
c.style.width="80%";
c.style.margin="10%"
c.style.imageRendering='pixelated';
```

```
181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 34 177 76 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 201 14 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 201 14 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 200 191 231 200 191 231 200 191 231 200 191 231 200 191 231 34 177 76 200 191 231 34 177 76 34 177 76 200 191 231 34 177 76 200 191 231 200 191 231 200 191 231 200 191 231 34 177 76 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 200 191 231 181 230 29 181 230 29 34 177 76 200 191 231 34 177 76 255 201 14 200 191 231 153 217 234 200 191 231 34 177 76 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 200 191 231 181 230 29 34 177 76 34 177 76 200 191 231 200 191 231 200 191 231 200 191 231 153 217 234 200 191 231 200 191 231 200 191 231 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 201 14 200 191 231 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 200 191 231 34 177 76 34 177 76 200 191 231 153 217 234 200 191 231 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 200 191 231 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 201 14 200 191 231 34 177 76 34 177 76 200 191 231 153 217 234 200 191 231 200 191 231 200 191 231 200 191 231 34 177 76 255 201 14 34 177 76 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 201 14 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 153 217 234 153 217 234 153 217 234 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 201 14 181 230 29 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 185 122 87 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 185 122 87 255 201 14 34 177 76 185 122 87 185 122 87 153 217 234 153 217 234 185 122 87 185 122 87 185 122 87 34 177 76 34 177 76 185 122 87 185 122 87 34 177 76 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 181 230 29 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 185 122 87 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 201 14 185 122 87 153 217 234 185 122 87 153 217 234 153 217 234 185 122 87 153 217 234 185 122 87 153 217 234 153 217 234 185 122 87 153 217 234 185 122 87 153 217 234 185 122 87 34 177 76 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 185 122 87 34 177 76 185 122 87 34 177 76 185 122 87 153 217 234 185 122 87 255 201 14 153 217 234 185 122 87 153 217 234 185 122 87 185 122 87 185 122 87 153 217 234 255 201 14 185 122 87 153 217 234 185 122 87 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 185 122 87 34 177 76 185 122 87 34 177 76 153 217 234 153 217 234 185 122 87 185 122 87 153 217 234 153 217 234 185 122 87 153 217 234 185 122 87 185 122 87 153 217 234 185 122 87 185 122 87 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 153 217 234 153 217 234 153 217 234 255 201 14 153 217 234 153 217 234 153 217 234 255 201 14 153 217 234 153 217 234 153 217 234 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 201 14 34 177 76 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 239 228 176 239 228 176 239 228 176 153 217 234 153 217 234 239 228 176 239 228 176 239 228 176 255 201 14 153 217 234 153 217 234 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 239 228 176 153 217 234 153 217 234 153 217 234 239 228 176 255 201 14 255 201 14 153 217 234 153 217 234 153 217 234 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 239 228 176 153 217 234 153 217 234 153 217 234 239 228 176 239 228 176 239 228 176 153 217 234 153 217 234 153 217 234 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 239 228 176 153 217 234 153 217 234 153 217 234 255 201 14 34 177 76 239 228 176 255 201 14 153 217 234 153 217 234 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 239 228 176 239 228 176 239 228 176 153 217 234 255 201 14 239 228 176 239 228 176 239 228 176 34 177 76 255 201 14 153 217 234 153 217 234 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 153 217 234 153 217 234 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 201 14 153 217 234 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 34 177 76 255 174 201 255 174 201 255 174 201 255 174 201 34 177 76 255 174 201 255 174 201 255 174 201 255 174 201 255 174 201 34 177 76 255 174 201 255 174 201 255 174 201 34 177 76 255 174 201 255 174 201 255 174 201 255 174 201 34 177 76 255 174 201 255 174 201 255 174 201 255 174 201 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 34 177 76 255 174 201 34 177 76 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 201 14 34 177 76 255 174 201 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 174 201 34 177 76 255 174 201 34 177 76 255 174 201 255 201 14 34 177 76 255 174 201 255 201 14 255 174 201 34 177 76 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 34 177 76 255 174 201 255 174 201 255 174 201 255 174 201 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 174 201 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 174 201 255 174 201 255 174 201 34 177 76 255 174 201 255 174 201 255 174 201 255 174 201 34 177 76 255 174 201 255 174 201 255 174 201 255 174 201 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 174 201 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 174 201 34 177 76 34 177 76 181 230 29 255 174 201 34 177 76 255 174 201 34 177 76 255 174 201 34 177 76 255 174 201 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 174 201 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 174 201 255 174 201 255 174 201 255 174 201 34 177 76 255 201 14 34 177 76 255 174 201 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 174 201 181 230 29 255 174 201 34 177 76 255 174 201 255 201 14 34 177 76 255 174 201 255 201 14 255 174 201 255 174 201 255 174 201 255 174 201 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 201 14 34 177 76 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 34 177 76 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 34 177 76 34 177 76 34 177 76 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29 255 201 14 181 230 29 181 230 29 181 230 29
```

Comment: The text was moved out of the question, so this code doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @Scimonster - fixed that, should work now.

Comment: I thought I knew JavaScript but apparently I don't since I'd never have been able to come up with this. I think this is the first time I've seen it used to solve a puzzle on here.

Comment: @Quark Very handy for puzzles like this and always ready to go when you're browsing the internet.